# Spray GET request is automatically triggered upon activation

Tags: spray

I'm using Spray to write an API for the web backend. One API is a `GET` type API that retrieves a URL of a document and send the URL as JSON. I know based on REST standard, `GET` is not supposed to create any side-effect, but this is the API for users to complete a task, and I want to give each user different task (thus marking retrieved documents as `retrieved` in my database).

It seems like Spray-routing pre-executes all `GET` request and cache them. Every time I send the http request to that API, I get the same document returned, not a different one.

My question is: I still want to use `GET` request, because I think it's the most natural verb for this task, but how can I achieve my task - returning different document URL each time and safely creating side-effect?

Maybe I should just use a different verb? But which one?

The original code is:

```
              get {
                val response = (secCompanyActor ? WebGetOneCompany).mapTo[TransOk]
                  .map(result => result.succeedOrNot match {
                  case true => (OK, result.company.get)
                  case false => (BadRequest, result.errorMessage) //no more company left
                })
                complete(response)
              }
```

Comment: Code is executed at route construction time unless it is in an extraction: http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/advanced-topics/understanding-dsl-structure/#understanding-extractions  Unless you post code I can't confirm this is the case, but it's gotten me before.

Comment: @Gangstead I read the documentation. It seems like I need to put logics inside `complete{...}` however, is this like `for...yield`, only the last line of code is the result returned?

Answer (score 1):

I modified my code as this:

```
         get {
                complete{
                  val response = (secCompanyActor ? WebGetOneCompany).mapTo[TransOk]
                    .map(result => result.succeedOrNot match {
                    case true => (OK, result.company.get)
                    case false => (BadRequest, result.errorMessage) //no more company left
                  })
                  response
                }
              }
```